# styled props color, not working to change movie names

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add some **css rules** to my movie **component**, however I am running into some problems.
For some reason my "*const StyledMovie = styled(MOVIE)*" seem to not change anything , where have I gone wrong? I would appreciate any help, as everything else seems to be working. I have ran into a logic error which are the hardest solve as a beginner so I came here,  best regards!

```js
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
 <title>ICS 211 - React</title>
 <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
 <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
 <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
 
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/styled-components/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>
 
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <style>
   html {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
   }
   hr {
    color: blue;
   }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
 const TITLE =() =>{
  return <div>
   <StyledTitleh1>My Top 3 Movies</StyledTitleh1>
   <StyledTitleh3>name</StyledTitleh3>
  </div>;
  }
 const MOVIE =({name,link}) => {
  
  
  
  return <div><li >{name}<a href={link}>{link}</a></li></div>
 }


 const App=({ className })=>(
  <div className={className}>
  
  <TITLE />
   <ol >
   
   
    <MOVIE name="Boyz n the Hood: " link="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101507/" color="blue"/>
    <MOVIE name="The Shawshank Redemption: " link="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/" color="green" />
    <MOVIE name="World War Z: " link="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816711/" color="red"/>
    
   </ol>
 </div>);
 
 const StyledApp = styled(App)`
background-color: papayawhip;

box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px gray;

padding: 10px;
`;
const StyledTitleh1 = styled.h1`
color: blue;
font-family: sans-serif;
`;

const StyledTitleh3 = styled.h3`
color: red;
  font-family: courier;`;

  const StyledMovie = styled(MOVIE)`
padding: 10px;
color: ${props => props.color};

`;


 ReactDOM.render(<StyledApp />, document.getElementById('container'));
 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not using `StyledMovie` in your code after creating it.

Change `MOVIE` component to use  the `className` property from `styled-component`

```
const `MOVIE` =({name,link, className}) => {    
        return <div className={className}><li >{name}<a href={link}>{link}</a></li></div>
    }
```

And in your `App` component use `StyledMovie` instead of `MOVIE`

```
const App=({ className })=>(
        <div className={className}>

        <TITLE />
            <ol >


                <StyledMovie name="Boyz n the Hood: " link="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101507/" color="blue"/>
                <StyledMovie name="The Shawshank Redemption: " link="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/" color="green" />
                <StyledMovie name="World War Z: " link="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816711/" color="red"/>

        </ol>
    </div>);
```